# Insert datetime into database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, laravel, insert

I have some difficulties with inserting date (type: datetime) into my database.
Whatever I put there, it throws me syntax errors about the date format etc. Could someone help me please?

```
DB::insert('INSERT INTO hidden_authors (e_user = ? AND h_user = ? AND h_change_time = ?)', array($userBanId, $id, date(Y-m-d H:i:s) ));
```

I have already tried to use sql getdate() but it also gives me an error.

Comment: add quotes for `date()`

Comment: It looks like `e_user.h_change_time` *should* be a `timestamp` field in the database anyway - with `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` ... which would make this entire question moot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Error Because of missing `"` inside `date()` function**.

change this to

```
date(Y-m-d H:i:s)
```

this

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

So **final Well Form code** should be

```
DB::insert('INSERT INTO hidden_authors (e_user = ? AND h_user = ? AND h_change_time = ?)',array($userBanId, $id, date("Y-m-d H:i:s")));
```

[PHP `date()` Function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp)

> ## **Tip For Your Code:**
>
> ***Without add exact function in query***, assign that to ***variable and call*** it to your query

Example :

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

So inside Query

```
DB::insert('INSERT INTO hidden_authors (e_user = ? AND h_user = ? AND h_change_time = ?)',array($userBanId, $id, $date));
```

> So when you read that `insert` function **you can get clear idea** about
>
> 1. ***what you did?***
> 2. ***what you need to do?***
> 3. ***where is the error??***
>
> Its simply point all of these questions

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. Unfortunately i still have a syntax error around h_change_time. Do you know why?

Comment: Try this **(new)** `DB::insert('insert into hidden_authors (e_user, h_user,h_change_time ) values (?, ?, ? )', array($userBanId, $id, $date));`

Comment: updated new `insert` use this `DB::insert('insert into hidden_authors (e_user, h_user,h_change_time ) values (?, ?, ? )', array($userBanId, $id, $date));`

Answer (score 3):

you have missed quotes for your `date()`. This should help you.

```
DB::insert('INSERT INTO hidden_authors (e_user = ? , h_user = ? , h_change_time = ?)',
     array($userBanId, $id, date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ));
                                 ^           ^
```

Comment: Its always a good practice to use single quotes rather than double quotes where we have any PHP code in a string. PHP parses everything inside double quotes therefore takes more time to dun the same script comparing to the one having single quotes

Comment: i added double coz, he has single quotes in his query.

Comment: that wont bother. PHP will parse date function string separately

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. Unfortunately i still have a syntax error around h_change_time. Do you know why?

Comment: replace and my comma `,`

Comment: {"error":{"type":"Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException","message":"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= ?, h_user = ?, h_change_time = ?)' at line 1 (SQL: INSERT INTO hidden_authors (e_user = 9, h_user = 7, h_change_time = 2015-10-13 14:47:23))","file":"C:\\Users\\theUser\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\myproject\\trunk\\newproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php","line":625}}

Comment: see this link, i think there in some syntax error, http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#inserts

Answer (score 1):

mysql datetime NOW()

```
DB::insert('INSERT INTO hidden_authors (e_user = ? AND h_user = ? AND 
h_change_time = ?)', array($userBanId, $id, NOW() ));
```